# Resistance in A.C. circuits

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Why do electromagnets offer maximum resistance in A.C. circuits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An electromagnet has a lot of turns of wire, which gives it a property called *inductance* : the property of resisting a change in the current. You may be familiar with Lenz's Law

$$V=-L\frac{d\Phi}{dt}$$

which says that an inductor with inductance $L$ will generate a back e.m.f. $V$ when the flux $\Phi$ through it changes. Now if you drive a current through an inductor, the act of sending the current will change the flux, and will therefore generate a "back e.m.f.". Which looks a lot like the voltage that is generated across a resistor when you drive a current through it.

Now if the current is of the form $I=I_0 \sin \omega t$, then the rate of change of flux will be proportional to the rate of change in current, $\Phi\propto I_0 \omega \cos\omega t$ and therefore be proportional to the frequency $\omega$.

This means that the back e.m.f. will increase with frequency, and the resistance felt will also increase. In fact, if you know how to use complex numbers, an inductor with a DC resistance $R$ and inductance $L$ will have a complex impedance

$$Z = j\omega L + R$$

We use complex numbers because the back e.m.f. is out of phase with the current (when you differentiate $\sin$ you get $\cos$... The magnitude of this impedance is

$$|Z| = \sqrt{\omega^2L^2 + R^2}$$

At large frequencies, the series resistance will become almost irrelevant, and the impedance will be proportional to the frequency.

**UPDATE**

It was pointed out by CuriousOne that there is an additional complication. An inductor typically has some (stray, parasitic) parallel capacitance. This is caused, for example, by the fact that adjacent windings act as a very small capacitor. With capacitance in parallel with inductance, the complex impedance becomes

$$Z = \frac{(R + j\omega L)\frac{1}{j\omega C}}{R+j\omega L + \frac{1}{j\omega C}}\\
=\frac{R + j\omega L}{j\omega RC - \omega^2 LC+1}$$

If $R$ is small, then this will reach a maximum when $\omega^2 LC = 1$ - this is the condition for resonance of the coil. At even higher frequencies, the impedance will increase again, as the parallel capacitance becomes a better and better path for the electrical current to bypass the inductor.

While this effect is real, it will only show up at very high frequencies - typically beyond the range where you would want to use an electromagnet.

Comment: You almost got it... at large frequencies the parallel capacitance of the inductor will take over and the impedance will first go trough a resonance and then it will go down with $1/\omega$ above that. The max. impedance of the inductor is at the resonance frequency.

Comment: @CuriousOne - you are right. I was afraid that adding that complexity would not help OP. But since "a lot got cleared up", maybe I can now add that...

Comment: @Floris... I got it (and gave +1). In practice the range between inductive behavior and capacitive behavior is usually not that large... a couple orders of magnitude in frequency, typically. I have never seen more than about 4 decades, even in the most carefully designed part unless we are talking superconductors, that is.